# Precise width of a monospace character

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm working on a code editor with syntax highlighting and I need to know the precise width of a monospace character. I use this value to calculate the position of a character on a line, which I need to know so I can place various GUI elements, such as text cursors (there can be multiple), selection rectangles, warning tooltips, etc. Up until now I've been using the following function:

```js
    function getCharacterWidth(char, fontFamily, fontSize) {
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        span.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
        span.style.fontSize = fontSize;
        span.style.position = "absolute";
        span.style.visibility = "hidden";
        span.style.width = "auto";
        span.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
        span.style.padding = "0";
        span.style.margin = "0";
        span.style.letterSpacing = "0px";
        span.style.wordSpacing = "0px";
        span.innerText = char;
        document.body.appendChild(span);
        
        let width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        span.remove();
        
        return width;
    }
```

It has been working great, but then I noticed a problem on Google Chrome. When my text editor is rendering a large line, with thousands of characters, the character position is not being properly calculated because of rounding issues. It seems that on Google Chrome, the `width` returned by `getBoundingClientRect()` has a precision of at most 5 decimal places, which is not ideal for my use case. On Firefox, the precision seems to be much higher, going up to 15 decimal places, which is why I never had this problem there.

After some digging, I heard about this idea of calculating the width of a character based on the width of a span containing thousands of that character (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56379770/2197150). So, in my original function I replaced `span.innerText = char` with `span.innerText = char.repeat(10000)` and returned `width / 10000`. It helped, but the calculation is still perceptibly off when I'm dealing with large lines.

So here I am. How can I calculate the width of a character with high precision, like Firefox does, in other browsers?

Comment: "*calculate the position of a character [on] a line*" - can't you just construct a [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) containing that character, then [get the bounding rectangle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) of that?

Comment: That could work, but if I could avoid searching the line looking for the element containing the character, it would be better. This is something I didn't mention, but my editor is actually a source code editor with syntax highlight, so a line in my editor is an "array of spans", which is how I stylize keywords, numbers, strings, etc. As I understand it, in order to get the chacater coordinates with a Range, the range would have to be constructed with the span in which the character is contained, which would require a lookup.

Comment: With a precise charater width, I can just do `charColumn * charWidth` to calculate its horizontal position.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. But what's your actual use case, where do you get the character index from and what do you want to do with the screen coordinates?

Comment: I use the coordinates to place a variety of visual elements, such as text cursors (there can be multiple), text selection rectangles, warning tooltips, etc. The character index is either calculated (e.g., upon clicking on the editor), or comes calculated beforehand (e.g., it is stored in a database and restore in the next time the editor is used, or it can come from the code checker, etc).

Comment: Ah, I suppose it's not possible to use a `Selection` then…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution that has been working well for *my use case*. The idea is to calculate the width of a character based on the largest line of my editor. My line elements look something like this:

```
<div class="line"><span class="keyword">let</span><span class="space"> </span><span class="identifier">foo</span></div>
```

If we want to calculate the width of a character based on that line, here is what we do:

```
let lineElement = document.querySelector(".line");
let lineWidth = lineElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let charWidth = lineWidth / lineElement.textContent.length;
```

I keep track of the largest line I've rendered in my editor. Whenever I render a new largest line, I update `charWidth` based on that new line.

This allows me to calculate the position of a character at any given column within a line by doing a simple multiplication `column * charWidth`. It has been working pretty well so far, even for lines with 100000+ characters.

There is, however, one last thing I had to do to handle even larger lines. It seems that there is a bug on Google Chrome where, when you try to render a line with a huge text node, e.g. `<span>many many characters...</span>`, it will not give you the correct width of the element (see [Inaccurate width of large element on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68686607/inaccurate-width-of-large-element-on-chrome)). To overcome this issue, whenever I  have to render a huge text, I split it into multiple spans, e.g. `<span>many many </span><span>characters...</span>`.

Now I can render 500000 characters long lines with font size 48 with no problems. Above that, things start to get weird again, with miscalculations and other weird browser behaviors. So I decided to set a hard limit of 500000 characters rendered in a line. Everything beyond the 500000nth characters is hidden from the user.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a clean solution, but I suspect there is no really clean solution.

You could keep a "column map", based on the syntax formatting `<span>`s you already have flying around. Say your highlighter gives you:

```
<div class="line">
var long_line_of_variables = <span class="number">123</span>;
</div>
```

you could measure this span's left offset + the column it appears in (= length of textContent of the siblings before it = 29) and arrive at

```
colums = {
  '29': 290.456
}
```

Now you can interpolate that column 14 is at `290.456*14/29=140.22` pixels.
The more spans we add, the better we can guess:

```
colums = {
  '29': 290.456,
  '2900': 28997.000 // whoops, not what we would have calculated!
}
```

This method is heuristic, so you'll need to find a strategy, which will work across browsers, zoom/font-scale settings etc., including

- adding more and more spans to this "map"
- but maybe "cleaning" it once in a while?
- keep a global map or *one per line*?
- be smart about interpolation: pick the nearest map entry (in the best interval between entries)
- add more "span probes"

  - split long lines without any formatting into chunks of N characters, wrapping them in spans, or inserting empty spans in between
  - maybe just a probe span right at the end of each line?

---

Having worked on similar problems and heuristics, my advice would be: don't. :)
It involves lots of tweaking and testing, and probably is a cross-platform nightmare (e.g. compare font rendering and rounding in Firefox on Win vs Linux vs MacOS vs iOS). Instead, try to attach *anything* to a localized span. I understand that this is probably way harder -- lots of text editors struggle with long lines, esp. when it comes to MB-size compiled JS...

Comment: Since I asked the question I came up with something that is kind of similar to your answer. I don't quite understand the motivation behind keeping a column map, but I would like to hear it. You see, in my new approach is similar to your answer with two exceptions. First, instead of basing my calculations on the left offset, I base it on the width of the line element (`getBoundingClientRect().width`). Second, instead of keeping a map of columns, all I do is to update the char width calculation whenever I render a new largest line.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to keep a column map is if the browser decides, for some weird reason, to place my spans not in their natural position (i.e., subsequently in the same line).

Comment: @DaviDoro the motivations behind my column map were: a. I didn't know you had a line length, which seems quite obvious now; b. I anticipated that the character width could change mid line (think a line of 1000 M's followed by 1000 I's -- I could see the browser rendering the M part slightly wider), which seems unlikely now.
Was your longest-line-width approach successful? If so, you could answer your own question and mark it correct, so I benefit when I randomly come back here in 7 years :)

Comment: to clarify re: Ms and Is: I wasn't referring to monospace vs variable-width; just the slightest differences in character widths and rounding errors accumulating. Again, seems unlikely, given that their boxes are probably exactly the same width in a monospace font file.

Comment: Yes, good thing I haven't had problems with differences in width of characters, at least not on Chrome/Firefox. Other browsers are still yet to be tested. If that happens, I think I'll just set a lower limit on the visible line length. At any rate, thanks for taking your time to write a detailed answer!