# Inaccurate width of large element on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114

When you create a large line of text on Chrome, the width of the element containing the line is incorrect. Example:

```js
document.querySelector("span").innerText = "a".repeat(40000)
```

```html
<span style="white-space: nowrap" contenteditable></span>
```

This will display a span with extra space at the end. If you try to edit at the end, you will see that the text cursor is misplaced.

I know what you are thinking: "why would you ever need Chrome to display a line that long?!". The answer is I don't really need Chrome to display it. I'm trying to workaround another limitation of Chrome, related to the precision with which the width of an element is calculated (see [Precise width of a monospace character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658100/precise-width-of-a-monospace-character)).

Thoughts?

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I posted a link because of the SO character limit, so I could not fit enough characters in the `span` to reproduce the issue. In any case, I edited with an example that uses Javascript.